# Azure Service bus, Error: Cannot create a message receiver on an entity with auto-forwarding enabled

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

```
Error: Cannot create a message receiver on an entity with auto-forwarding enabled.
```

I enabled the auto-forwarding and then disabled it using the Azure service bus explorer.
Now, I want to listen to the topic subscription(I had enabled and then disabled the auto-forwarding.) and getting the above-mentioned error.

I know, We can not listen the topic subscription in which auto-forwarding is enabled. but, In my case, I have disabled it and then try to listing the topic subscription.

also, I tried to delete the subscription and added it again with the same name. but, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the entity was deleted and recreated without forwarding (assuming it was) but still has forwarding on, there are two options:

1. The entity was recreated incorrectly. Try again.
2. The namespace is in a faulty state and a fix needs to be applied on the service side. Open a support case with Azure support.

Comment: maybe this was the case. but, not sure what was happened. I had to delete the topic with subscriptions and create a new one again with subscriptions and it works now. thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best 